# ASP.NET core web API routing not supported in AWS HTTP API Gateway?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-http-api

I am trying to transfer an asp.net core web api to my first AWS HTTP API.
I have hosted the asp.net core web api project as a lambda function, and trying to match the endpoints through the API gateway.
I can access the default endpoints though my API gateway. i.e. the following endpoint can be accessed through my api gateway successfully.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value10", "value200" };
        }
...
}
```

[image]

But, I get a 404 not found exception if I try to access some method with a Route attribute. e.g.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ReportsController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet, Route("GetReports")]
        public IEnumerable<string> GetReports()
        {
            return new string[] { "value100", "value2000" };
        }
    }
```

with the following mapping
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

thanks,

Comment: What is your lambda initialization function?

Comment: I am using the serverless.AspNetCoreWebAPI template to create my lambda function. If I understood your question correctly, my LambdaEntryPoint class extends from Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyFunction

Comment: Ah, I think I figured out the problem, I was missing the package reference of Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer. now the GetReports route resolves, thanks @JohnGlenn for pointing at the right direction!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad you got it working.